# Sort PHP array base on its value

Tags: php

When I did

```
$result = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray());
$result = asort($result,SORT_NATURAL);
return $result;
```

I kept getting

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

[image]

This is an array

```
array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray())
```

It returns

```
{
    iPhone: 202,
    Windows NT 6.1: 2428,
    Windows NT 10.0: 2588,
    Macintosh: 1397,
    iPad: 12,
    Windows NT 6.2: 50,
    Windows NT 6.3: 90,
    X11: 442,
    compatible: 1813,
    Windows NT 5.1: 97,
    Linux: 227,
    Windows: 86,
    TweetmemeBot/4.0: 8,
    ) { :: 14,
    Windows NT 6.0: 7,
    User-Agent,Mozilla/5.0 : 1,
    KHTML, like Gecko: 6,
    Unknown: 11,
    Android: 1,
    Android 7.1.1: 1,
    Android 7.1.2: 2,
    Windows NT x.y: 2,
    Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 : 7,
    Windows NT 5.0: 1,
    Windows NT 8.0: 1,
    web crawler :: robots.txt exclude elefent: 1,
    Windows NT: 1,
    Linux 4.4.0-116-generic: 1
}
```

I want to sort them in a desc base on `values`.

Please help

Comment: `asort()` sorts the array in place, no need to resassign

Comment: @axiac : please remove your downvote. I added texts now.

Comment: @BrettGregson : How do I do it on a DESC order ?

Answer (score 1):

`asort()` returns a boolean indicating whether the operation was successful or not. What you want to do instead is this :

```
$result = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray());
asort($result,SORT_NATURAL);

return $result;
```

See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) for more information

Comment: How do I do it on a DESC order ?

Answer (score 1):

[`asort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) returns a boolean indicating if the sort was managed ok or not. It sorts the array by reference.

Change your code to:

```
$result = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray());
asort($result,SORT_NATURAL);
//$result is now sorted.
return $result;
```

Comment: How do I do it on a DESC order ?

Answer (score 1):

`asort()` does not return the sorted array but a boolean to say if it's done (`true`) or not (`false`)

```
$result = array_count_values(Visitor::all()->pluck('device')->toArray());
asort($result, SORT_NATURAL);
return $result;
```

Comment: How do I do it on a DESC order ?

Comment: Use `arsort()`. It does the same as `asort()` but in reverse order.